Fixing DLL Issues in WiX Setup Custom Actions
I have an issue when I start to install the setup installer. There's an error: 'There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.
What is the solution if there’s no error? And can the WiX Setup Installer create an installation package that cannot be installed if the user doesn't have one important file (like a license)?
I already have the application and it is working fine. However, my application requires one important file (.msilicense) that the user must have.
my code for CustomAction.cs
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
        {
            string licenseFilePath = session["LICENSEFILEPATH"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseFilePath) || !System.IO.File.Exists(licenseFilePath))
            {
                session.Log("License file not found.");
                MessageBox.Show("License file is missing. Installation cannot continue.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            session.Log("License file found, proceeding with installation.");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}

my code for product.wxs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define WixDemoApp_TargetDir=$(var.WixDemoApp.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="69cb3f17-e07d-4c52-a56b-dcb0a171f4f3" Name="WIX Application" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Tasya-Fauzia.com" UpgradeCode="0029baf3-428e-42f5-a3a9-9ea30e7c0caf">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <Icon Id="icon_notes.ico" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)icon_notes.ico" />
        <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon_notes.ico" />

        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Images\installer_top-banner.bmp" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Images\installer_background.bmp" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\license.rtf" />

        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WIX Application" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />
        </Feature>
    
        <CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" BinaryKey="CustomAction.dll" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
        
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="CustomAction1" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="TESTFILEPRODUCTDIR" Name="WIX Application">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WIX Application" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="WIX Application" />
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
    
    <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="9bd13330-6540-406f-a3a8-d7f7c69ae7f9">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="WixDemoApp" Description="WixDemoApp" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]WixDemoApp.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\WixDemoApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="cde1e030-eb64-49a5-b7b8-400b379c2d1a">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="WixDemoApp" Description="WixDemoApp" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]WixDemoApp.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\WixDemoApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Binary Id="CustomAction.dll" SourceFile="$(var.WixDemoApp_TargetDir)CustomAction.dll"/>
        
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->
            <Component Id="WixDemoApp.exe" Guid="843db6f1-4945-460f-8970-5eb7a2bce138">
              <File Id="WixDemoApp.exe" Name="WixDemoApp.exe" Source="$(var.WixDemoApp_TargetDir)WixDemoApp.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="WixDemoApp.exe.config" Guid="0dd947be-2a56-4f04-b8dc-d353d47be39c">
              <File Id="WixDemoApp.exe.config" Name="WixDemoApp.exe.config" Source="$(var.WixDemoApp_TargetDir)WixDemoApp.exe.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="WIXDepedency.dll" Guid="2ad1f454-a0ca-47d5-a422-657c8e9fab29">
              <File Id="WIXDepedency.dll" Name="WIXDepedency.dll" Source="$(var.WixDemoApp_TargetDir)WIXDepedency.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="CustomAction.dll" Guid="3a45ab64-a477-4bf1-b6da-0c25eabe4d89">
              <File Id="CustomAction.dll" Name="CustomAction.dll" Source="$(var.WixDemoApp_TargetDir)CustomAction.dll" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>

